# Multiplication table in Python shows only six columns

Tags: python

I wrote a code in PyCharm and after running it, PyCharm and Python3 show only six columns.

```
layout = "{0:>2} {1:>2} {2:>2} {3:>2} {4:>2} {5:>2} {6:>2} {7:>2} {8:>2} {9:>2} {10:>2} {11:>2}"
def multiple_table2():
    for i in range (1, 11):
        print(layout.format(i, "\t", i*2, "\t", i*3, "\t", i*4, "\t", i*5, "\t", i*6, "\t", i*7, "\t", i*8, "\t", i*9, "\t", i*10, "\t", i*11, "\t", i*12))

multiple_table2()
```

I think, it is correct. Can me someone explain, please, where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting more than 12 values into your columns. The first 12 are 6 numbers and 6 tab characters. Each of those `"\t"` strings *is a value too*; you are essentially producing:

```
' 1  \t  2  \t  3  \t  4  \t  5  \t  6  \t'
```

as the string; note the spaces between! That's one space for values shorter than 2 characters, and another space from the template itself.

You don't need to put those tab characters into your format; you already spaced out the slots:

```
print(layout.format(i, i*2, i*3, i*4, i*5, i*6, i*7, i*8, i*9, i*10, i*11, i*12))
```

Now you pass in 12 arguments for 12 slots.

If you really wanted to put tabs in between you'd put those in the `layout` string instead:

```
layout = '{0:>2}\t{1:>2}\t{2:>2}\t{3:>2}\t{4:>2}\t{5:>2}\t{6:>2}\t{7:>2}\t{8:>2}\t{9:>2}\t{10:>2}\t{11:>2}'
```

Python gives you the tools to avoid having to type. `print()` already puts spaces in between separate arguments. Together with another loop in a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), you can format all those numbers without writing out all those `*multiplier` arguments:

```
for i in range (1, 11):
    print(*(format(i * m, '>2') for m in range(1, 13)))
```

If you still needed to have tabs in between instead of spaces, you can tell `print()` to use that as a separator using the `sep` argument:

```
for i in range (1, 11):
    print(*(format(i * m, '>2') for m in range(1, 13)), sep='\t')
```

Take into account that because you are multiplying by 11 and 12, you'll get numbers that won't fit in 2 characters:

```
>>> for i in range (1, 11):
...     print(*(format(i * m, '>2') for m in range(1, 13)))
... 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24
 3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36
 4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48
 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60
 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 66 72
 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 77 84
 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80 88 96
 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90 99 108
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120
```